# 非同期通信で会話機能を導入しているのですが、ページをリロードしないで、データを表示することができません。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

私は、今非同期通信で会話機能を導入しようと考えています。ページ移動なしで、データを表示することができるのですが、ページ移動・リロードなしで、表示することができない状態にあります。もしわかる方がいらしたら、方法を教えて頂きたいです。

```rb
if Entry.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :room_id => params[:message][:room_id]).present?
    @message = Message.new(params.require(:message).permit(:user_id, :content, :room_id).merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
    if @message.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to :action => "show", :controller=>"rooms", :id => @message.room_id }
            format.json 
        end
    end
else
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end
```

```rb
<% if @messages.present? %>
    <% @messages.each do |m| %>
    <strong><%= m.content %></strong>
    <small>by <strong><a href="/users/<%= m.user_id %>"><%= m.user.email %>さん</a></strong></small>
    <hr>
<% end %>
<% else %>
    <h3 class="text-center">メッセージはまだありません</h3>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @message,  id: "new_message" do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :content, class: "form__message", :placeholder => "メッセージを入力して下さい" , :size => 70 %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :room_id, class: "form__message", :value => @room.id %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "投稿する" , class: "form__message" %>
<% end %>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#new_message').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
        })
    }

    $("#new_message").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        function buildHTML(message){
        var html = `<div class="message">
                        <div class="upper-message">
                            <div class="upper-message__user-name">
                                ${ content }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
        }
        return false;

        function scroll() {
            $('.messages').animate({scrollTop: $('.message')[0].scrollHeight});
        }

        $("#new_message").on('submit', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            });

            .done(function(data){
                var html = buildHTML(data);
                $('.messages').append(html);
                $('.form__message').val('');
                $('.form__submit').prop('disabled', false);
            });
            scroll()
        });
    };
</script>
```

・jbuilder

```
json.id @message.id
json.content @message.content
json.room_id @message.room_id
json.user_id @message.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

単純な文法間違い？`$.ajax()`の後ろに`.done()`をつなげる前に`;`が入ってるからじゃないですかね？？

Answer (score 1):

問題を切り分けましょう。

【１、大前提として、jsやjQueryの基本的なミスがないか？】

・readyの外側で$(...).onバインドは一般的ではありません。
　処理順序を明確に理解してないのであれば、避けるべきでしょう。
　また、readyの書き方は、jQuery3.0以降であれば、$(handler)が推奨されています

・javascriptにミスがある様に見える
　buildHTML()ですが、message引数使ってないように見えます…？あとインデントは揃えましょう。

【２．Ajax処理周りの切り分け】

1. RailsのView（つまり生成されたhtml自体）にミスがある可能性
   　　→　chromeでF12を押して、実際に生成されたhtml DOMが自分の想定通りか確認してください
2. Ajaxで呼び出したURLに対するサーバ側が、うまくいっていない可能性
   　→　適当な関数でログをテキスト出力することは可能なはずです。
   　　　想定したサーバサイドのコントローラーが呼ばれたか確認してください。
3. Ajax通信が失敗している可能性
   　→　前提としてAjaxは、必ずdone, fail, alwaysをセットで書きましょう。
   　　　詳細はajaxのリファレンスを参照してください。
   　　　また、これらにalert()なりconsole.log()なりで、どれが実行されたかどうかを確認してください
   　　Ajax通信にはいくつかの制約があります
   　　・ページ自体とAjaxリクエストする先が同一生成元でない（クロスドメインである）場合、
   　　　サーバ側がCORS対処しないと失敗する
   　　・GETリクエストならjsonpで回避することは可能だがjsonpの場合、
   　　　エラーが発生したときにエラーの原因は読み取れない